# Django: save model object of a ModelForm

Tags: django

I have a ModelForm:

```
class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ['image']
```

which is based on model `Image`

```
class Image(models.Model):
    def content_file_name(instance, filename):
        return filename

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=content_file_name)
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, related_name='image')
```

In views.py, I try to save the image name and user object (from session) along with the uploaded image to database.

```
    form1 = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form1.is_valid():
        image = request.FILES['image']  # image is of UploadedFile class
        form1.Meta.model.name = image.name
        form1.Meta.model.user = get_object_or_404(MyUser,username=request.session['user'])
        form1.save()
        return render(request, '16_upload01.html', context)
```

Problem is **only the uploaded image gets saved**. Error message in browser:

> IntegrityError at /competition-big/big1/upload
>   comp_app_image.user_id may not be NULL

I confirmed this by checking on SQL command:

> INSERT INTO "comp_app_image" ("name", "image", "user_id") VALUES ('', 'grey-160-100_1.png', None)

I figure that **image name and user are not bounded to `form1`.** But how can I achieve that?

**EDIT**
After some digging, I know I messed up with above code. Now I changed my code to this:

```
if form1.is_valid():
        form1.cleaned_data['user'] = get_object_or_404(MyUser, username=request.session['user'])
        form1.save()
```

But I still get `null user_id` error.

**EDIT** 2
Thanks Jacinda. Now I get this cleaner code:

```
if form1.is_valid():
        form1.cleaned_data['user'] = request.user
        form1.save()
```

But error `null user_id` remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this form can only be accessed by a logged in user, use the [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator, and you should always redirect after a `POST`. You should also read [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use) in the ModelForms documentation; which describes how to properly use a model form that has limited fields.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def your_view(request):
  form1 = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
  if form1.is_valid():
      image = request.FILES['image']  # image is of UploadedFile class
      obj = form1.save(commit=False)
      obj.name = image.name
      obj.user = request.user
      obj.save()
      return redirect('your-view-name')
  else:
      return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form1})
```

Comment: +1 Your code works. And your explanation is concise and clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is probably this line:

```
form1.Meta.model.user = get_object_or_404(MyUser,username=request.session['user'])
```

When I try and use your syntax (using the Django default django.contrib.auth) I get a KeyError on 'user'.

What I've always done when I need information about  the user associated with a request is this:

`username = request.user.username`

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user

Of course, this will only work if your users are required to be logged in to upload images.

Comment: I use Django 1.5 and am utilizing a custom User model. Please see my Edit, the error might be caused by something else

Comment: You should still be able to use this syntax.  I also use Django 1.5 and even if you use a custom user model Django's built-in auth system can reference it if AUTH_USER_MODEL is specified in your settings and your custom user is compliant.  Are you also not using django.contrib.auth?  You are presumably still inheriting from either CustomUser, AbstractBaseUser or AbstractUser unless you're doing something really unique.

Comment: I tried `form1.cleaned_data['user'] = request.user`. It retrieve `MyUser` object as you said. But the error remain. I guess the error is due to left side of the equation?

Comment: I accept Khalid's answer because his code works. +1 for your answer too. Now I know `request.user` and it totally works with a custom user model!